# Laravel : Get all models that their last relationship have some condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models Post and Comment, i'd like to get all posts that their last comment is active:

```
// Model Post
public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('comments');
}

//Model Comment
public function post()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('post');
}
```

i tried this solution :

```
public function lastComment()
{
 return $this->hasOne('comment')->latest()
}
```

and in my controller :

```
$postsWithLastActiveComment = Post::whereHas('lastComment', function($q){
  $q->where('active',1);
})->all();
```

but in this solution if the last comment is not active Previous comment will be taken

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687657/4848587.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there's another simpler way of doing this, but maybe you can try it with a sub-query?

```
$lastComment = Comment::select('active')
    ->whereColumn('post_id', 'posts.id')
    ->latest()
    ->limit(1)
    ->getQuery();

$posts = Post::select('posts.*')
    ->selectSub($lastComment, 'last_comment_is_active')
    ->having('last_comment_is_active', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`->latest()` only orders the posts by created_at so to get only the latest comment you need `->latest()->first()`

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRelated()

Comment: first method is not allowed in relationship query

Comment: You're getting getRelated error because your Comments relation is a HasMany, not as HasOne (even though you only want one). So you can put: `$this->hasMany('comments')->latest()->first()`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below should work !

```
public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('comments');
}

public function lastComment()
{
  return $this->comments()->latest()->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this

```
$postsWithLastActiveComment = Post::whereHas('lastComment', function($q){
  $q->where('active',1);
})->all();
```

be

```
 $postsWithLastActiveComment = Post::whereHas('lastComment', function($q){
    $q->where('active',1);
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, the Post model has many Comments. And you want to **get the comment from the post where active is one and must be the lastest id**.

Get the last comment like the following

```
public function lastComment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('comment')->latest()->take(1);
}
```

Get all `posts` which had the `lastComment` like the following

```
$latestCommentPosts = Post::whereHas('lastComment')->get()
```

And filter the `latestCommentPosts` like the following

```
$latestCommentPosts->where('active', 1)->get()
```

Or, you can archive by one query like the following as well.

```
Post::whereHas('comments', function($q) { 
    $q->where('active', 1); 
})->get()
```

Like that, you got all the latest comment with active is 1.